# Arrays.deepHashCode() is not unique

Tags: java, arrays, hash

Why is `Arrays.deepHashCode()` not unique? What can I do to generate an unique hash of an array?

```
int[][] array1 = { { 8, 7, 4 }, { 3, 6, 5 }, { 0, 2, 1 } };
int[][] array2 = { { 8, 4, 0 }, { 6, 7, 5 }, { 3, 2, 1 } };

System.out.println("Hash array1 " + Arrays.deepHashCode(array1));
System.out.println("Hash array2 " + Arrays.deepHashCode(array2));
```

?!

```
Hash array1 37308160
Hash array2 37308160
```

Comment: "*Why is `Arrays.deepHashCode()` not unique?*" - Why should it? On a side note, you map multiple `int`s to one `int`, so it cannot be guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Hash codes are not guaranteed to be unique and in fact cannot be unique because of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). In other words: there is no such thing as a unique hash code, and what you want is impossible.

Comment: You can probably fairly easily write your own deep hash code method that will be more likely to generate different hash codes for two equal-sized but different 2D arrays of small numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The [`java.util.Arrays.deepHashCode(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepHashCode-java.lang.Object:A-) method returns a hash code based on the "deep contents" of the specified array.For any two arrays a and b such that [`Arrays.deepEquals(a, b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-), it is also the case that `Arrays.deepHashCode(a) == Arrays.deepHashCode(b)`.

As per javadoc:

```
public static int deepHashCode(Object[] a)
```

> Returns a hash code based on the "deep contents" of the specified
>   array. If the array contains other arrays as elements, the hash code
>   is based on their contents and so on, ad infinitum. It is therefore
>   unacceptable to invoke this method on an array that contains itself as
>   an element, either directly or indirectly through one or more levels
>   of arrays. The behavior of such an invocation is undefined. For any
>   two arrays a and b such that [`Arrays.deepEquals(a, b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-), it is also the
>   case that `Arrays.deepHashCode(a) == Arrays.deepHashCode(b)`.

Answer (score 3):

This does not break any Java contract. Hashcode should return distinct ints for different objects as often as possible, however it is not required.

The general contract of hashCode is:

Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.

- If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
- It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.